# Wolfram Alpha API wrapper for VB not working for C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, rest, wolframalpha

I'm using the Wolfram Alpha API wrapper for .NET at this location

http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/libraries.html

However it's written in VB.NET and written for version 1.0 of the API.  It's unusable.

Does anyone know of a better API wrapper?

Comment: Looks like the library for VB is made for version 1.0 'preview' syntax.  It's very much out of date.  Any references to a better wrapper is appreciated

Comment: So, the problem doesn't have anything to do with VB.NET. It's just an outdated wrapper? Because if it works in VB.NET, it will work with C#—*guaranteed*.

Comment: @mitch @cody The underlying REST api changed... the VB App will never work, even in a VB app.  It's not a C# vs VB issue, it's just that the underlying API changed and I don't see any modern implementations that work with .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that will work with the new API; I got it from Azure Dallas

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Notice: Use of the service proxies that accompany this notice is subject to
//            the terms and conditions of the license agreement located at
//            http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=202740&clcid=0x409
//            If you do not agree to these terms you may not use this content.
namespace WolframAlpha {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Services.Client;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;


    public partial class DefaultPodEntity {

        private String _PlainText;

        private String _Img;

        private String _Title;

        private String _ParentTitle;

        private Int16 _ParentPosition;

        private String _ParentId;

        public String PlainText {
            get {
                return this._PlainText;
            }
            set {
                this._PlainText = value;
            }
        }

        public String Img {
            get {
                return this._Img;
            }
            set {
                this._Img = value;
            }
        }

        public String Title {
            get {
                return this._Title;
            }
            set {
                this._Title = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentTitle {
            get {
                return this._ParentTitle;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentTitle = value;
            }
        }

        public Int16 ParentPosition {
            get {
                return this._ParentPosition;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentPosition = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentId {
            get {
                return this._ParentId;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class HtmlPodEntity {

        private String _Markup;

        private String _Title;

        private Int16 _Position;

        private String _Id;

        private String _Css;

        private String _Scripts;

        public String Markup {
            get {
                return this._Markup;
            }
            set {
                this._Markup = value;
            }
        }

        public String Title {
            get {
                return this._Title;
            }
            set {
                this._Title = value;
            }
        }

        public Int16 Position {
            get {
                return this._Position;
            }
            set {
                this._Position = value;
            }
        }

        public String Id {
            get {
                return this._Id;
            }
            set {
                this._Id = value;
            }
        }

        public String Css {
            get {
                return this._Css;
            }
            set {
                this._Css = value;
            }
        }

        public String Scripts {
            get {
                return this._Scripts;
            }
            set {
                this._Scripts = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class PlainTextPodEntity {

        private String _PlainText;

        private String _Title;

        private String _ParentTitle;

        private Int16 _ParentPosition;

        private String _ParentId;

        public String PlainText {
            get {
                return this._PlainText;
            }
            set {
                this._PlainText = value;
            }
        }

        public String Title {
            get {
                return this._Title;
            }
            set {
                this._Title = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentTitle {
            get {
                return this._ParentTitle;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentTitle = value;
            }
        }

        public Int16 ParentPosition {
            get {
                return this._ParentPosition;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentPosition = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentId {
            get {
                return this._ParentId;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class WolframAlphaFactsContainer : System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext {

        public WolframAlphaFactsContainer(Uri serviceRoot) : 
                base(serviceRoot) {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Input">Query string Sample Values : weather|msft|derivative of x^4 sin x|SAT scores</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Location used for computation Sample Values : Madrid|Springfield, IL</param>
        /// <param name="LatitudeLongitude">Latitude/Longitude used for computation Sample Values : 40.42,-3.71|-22.54,-43.12</param>
        /// <param name="Width">Width in pixels for images returned Sample Values : 300|500</param>
        public DataServiceQuery<DefaultPodEntity> GetImageResults(String Input, String Location, String LatitudeLongitude, Int16? Width) {
            if ((Input == null)) {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Input", "Input value cannot be null");
            }
            DataServiceQuery<DefaultPodEntity> query;
            query = base.CreateQuery<DefaultPodEntity>("GetImageResults");
            if ((Input != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Input", string.Concat("\'", Input, "\'"));
            }
            if ((Location != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Location", string.Concat("\'", Location, "\'"));
            }
            if ((LatitudeLongitude != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("LatitudeLongitude", string.Concat("\'", LatitudeLongitude, "\'"));
            }
            if (((Width != null) 
                        && (Width.HasValue == true))) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Width", Width.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Input">Query string Sample Values : weather|msft|derivative of x^4 sin x|SAT scores</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Location used for computation Sample Values : Madrid|Springfield, IL</param>
        /// <param name="LatitudeLongitude">Latitude/Longitude used for computation Sample Values : 40.42,-3.71|-22.54,-43.12</param>
        /// <param name="Width">Width in pixels for images returned Sample Values : 300|500</param>
        public DataServiceQuery<HtmlPodEntity> GetHtmlResults(String Input, String Location, String LatitudeLongitude, Int16? Width) {
            if ((Input == null)) {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Input", "Input value cannot be null");
            }
            DataServiceQuery<HtmlPodEntity> query;
            query = base.CreateQuery<HtmlPodEntity>("GetHtmlResults");
            if ((Input != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Input", string.Concat("\'", Input, "\'"));
            }
            if ((Location != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Location", string.Concat("\'", Location, "\'"));
            }
            if ((LatitudeLongitude != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("LatitudeLongitude", string.Concat("\'", LatitudeLongitude, "\'"));
            }
            if (((Width != null) 
                        && (Width.HasValue == true))) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Width", Width.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Input">Query string Sample Values : weather|msft|derivative of x^4 sin x|SAT scores</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Location used for computation Sample Values : Madrid|Springfield, IL</param>
        /// <param name="LatitudeLongitude">Latitude/Longitude used for computation Sample Values : 40.42,-3.71|-22.54,-43.12</param>
        /// <param name="Width">Width in pixels for images returned Sample Values : 300|500</param>
        public DataServiceQuery<PlainTextPodEntity> GetPlainTextResults(String Input, String Location, String LatitudeLongitude, Int16? Width) {
            if ((Input == null)) {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Input", "Input value cannot be null");
            }
            DataServiceQuery<PlainTextPodEntity> query;
            query = base.CreateQuery<PlainTextPodEntity>("GetPlainTextResults");
            if ((Input != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Input", string.Concat("\'", Input, "\'"));
            }
            if ((Location != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Location", string.Concat("\'", Location, "\'"));
            }
            if ((LatitudeLongitude != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("LatitudeLongitude", string.Concat("\'", LatitudeLongitude, "\'"));
            }
            if (((Width != null) 
                        && (Width.HasValue == true))) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Width", Width.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link for more detail to this? I'm trying to work with it but as I'm new to C# (coming from Java) I'm having trouble getting the code to work (It compiles I just can't get any output or figure out how to print the results to console or a label) and it doesn't seem to pass the APPID, don't you need that?

Comment: @nick `Console.Write( "Hello World" );` is how you get stuff to a console.  Put a text box or label on your screen and type `label1.text = "hello world"`.  Once you do that, then work on this class.  To be honest I haven't looked at this in over a year so I forget how to use it.  Check the Azure Dallas web services site.