# Reference System.Data.Services.Client

Tags: c#, wolframalpha

I'm using VS C# 2010 Express and I am trying to use the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834913/wolfram-alpha-api-wrapper-for-vb-not-working-for-c-sharp) but I am getting an error on the import:

```
using System.Data.Services.Client;
```

I tried to add a reference to it but can't find the item anywhere, assuming that is indeed the problem. Any direction on how I can get this code to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're targeting framework version 3.5 or later?  Both the Full Framework and Client Profile >= 3.5 should present this as an option when attempting to add it as a reference through VS.

Comment: That is odd.  The location of the assembly on disk should be in "\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Services.Client.dll" - can you verify the same?

Comment: yes, I actually found many of them. Is there a way to directly reference it?

Comment: figured it out :) the reference was in the .net tab must of overlooked it

Answer (score 0):

I find sometimes Visual Studio plays up a little with this.  It is worth going to the Project Pages and setting the .Net Framework to any version and then back to 4.0.

Basically turning it off and on again!