# C# Wolfram aplha API working example

Tags: c#, wolframalpha

I have been trying to get the Wolframalpha API for `C#` working to no avail. I have been trying to use these two resources:

1. [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834913/wolfram-alpha-api-wrapper-for-vb-not-working-for-c-sharp)
2. [Wolfram API demos](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/libraries.html)

The answer in the post was semi helpful but I can't get anything to compile. I'm new to C# so its a bit overwhelming. I am really having trouble trying to just get it to accept input and then output the result.

**If anyone could either help me get this code working so I can work with a valid example or knows of an example project that I can model from it would be appreciated.**

This is the code I cut and pasted into a C# (Visual Studio) console project:

```
    namespace WolframAlpha {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Services.Client;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;


    public partial class DefaultPodEntity {

        private String _PlainText;

        private String _Img;

        private String _Title;

        private String _ParentTitle;

        private Int16 _ParentPosition;

        private String _ParentId;

        public String PlainText {
            get {
                return this._PlainText;
            }
            set {
                this._PlainText = value;
            }
        }

        public String Img {
            get {
                return this._Img;
            }
            set {
                this._Img = value;
            }
        }

        public String Title {
            get {
                return this._Title;
            }
            set {
                this._Title = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentTitle {
            get {
                return this._ParentTitle;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentTitle = value;
            }
        }

        public Int16 ParentPosition {
            get {
                return this._ParentPosition;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentPosition = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentId {
            get {
                return this._ParentId;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class HtmlPodEntity {

        private String _Markup;

        private String _Title;

        private Int16 _Position;

        private String _Id;

        private String _Css;

        private String _Scripts;

        public String Markup {
            get {
                return this._Markup;
            }
            set {
                this._Markup = value;
            }
        }

        public String Title {
            get {
                return this._Title;
            }
            set {
                this._Title = value;
            }
        }

        public Int16 Position {
            get {
                return this._Position;
            }
            set {
                this._Position = value;
            }
        }

        public String Id {
            get {
                return this._Id;
            }
            set {
                this._Id = value;
            }
        }

        public String Css {
            get {
                return this._Css;
            }
            set {
                this._Css = value;
            }
        }

        public String Scripts {
            get {
                return this._Scripts;
            }
            set {
                this._Scripts = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class PlainTextPodEntity {

        private String _PlainText;

        private String _Title;

        private String _ParentTitle;

        private Int16 _ParentPosition;

        private String _ParentId;

        public String PlainText {
            get {
                return this._PlainText;
            }
            set {
                this._PlainText = value;
            }
        }

        public String Title {
            get {
                return this._Title;
            }
            set {
                this._Title = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentTitle {
            get {
                return this._ParentTitle;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentTitle = value;
            }
        }

        public Int16 ParentPosition {
            get {
                return this._ParentPosition;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentPosition = value;
            }
        }

        public String ParentId {
            get {
                return this._ParentId;
            }
            set {
                this._ParentId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class WolframAlphaFactsContainer : System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext {

        public WolframAlphaFactsContainer(Uri serviceRoot) : 
                base(serviceRoot) {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Input">Query string Sample Values : weather|msft|derivative of x^4 sin x|SAT scores</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Location used for computation Sample Values : Madrid|Springfield, IL</param>
        /// <param name="LatitudeLongitude">Latitude/Longitude used for computation Sample Values : 40.42,-3.71|-22.54,-43.12</param>
        /// <param name="Width">Width in pixels for images returned Sample Values : 300|500</param>
        public DataServiceQuery<DefaultPodEntity> GetImageResults(String Input, String Location, String LatitudeLongitude, Int16? Width) {
            if ((Input == null)) {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Input", "Input value cannot be null");
            }
            DataServiceQuery<DefaultPodEntity> query;
            query = base.CreateQuery<DefaultPodEntity>("GetImageResults");
            if ((Input != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Input", string.Concat("\'", Input, "\'"));
            }
            if ((Location != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Location", string.Concat("\'", Location, "\'"));
            }
            if ((LatitudeLongitude != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("LatitudeLongitude", string.Concat("\'", LatitudeLongitude, "\'"));
            }
            if (((Width != null) 
                        && (Width.HasValue == true))) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Width", Width.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Input">Query string Sample Values : weather|msft|derivative of x^4 sin x|SAT scores</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Location used for computation Sample Values : Madrid|Springfield, IL</param>
        /// <param name="LatitudeLongitude">Latitude/Longitude used for computation Sample Values : 40.42,-3.71|-22.54,-43.12</param>
        /// <param name="Width">Width in pixels for images returned Sample Values : 300|500</param>
        public DataServiceQuery<HtmlPodEntity> GetHtmlResults(String Input, String Location, String LatitudeLongitude, Int16? Width) {
            if ((Input == null)) {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Input", "Input value cannot be null");
            }
            DataServiceQuery<HtmlPodEntity> query;
            query = base.CreateQuery<HtmlPodEntity>("GetHtmlResults");
            if ((Input != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Input", string.Concat("\'", Input, "\'"));
            }
            if ((Location != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Location", string.Concat("\'", Location, "\'"));
            }
            if ((LatitudeLongitude != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("LatitudeLongitude", string.Concat("\'", LatitudeLongitude, "\'"));
            }
            if (((Width != null) 
                        && (Width.HasValue == true))) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Width", Width.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Input">Query string Sample Values : weather|msft|derivative of x^4 sin x|SAT scores</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Location used for computation Sample Values : Madrid|Springfield, IL</param>
        /// <param name="LatitudeLongitude">Latitude/Longitude used for computation Sample Values : 40.42,-3.71|-22.54,-43.12</param>
        /// <param name="Width">Width in pixels for images returned Sample Values : 300|500</param>
        public DataServiceQuery<PlainTextPodEntity> GetPlainTextResults(String Input, String Location, String LatitudeLongitude, Int16? Width) {
            if ((Input == null)) {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Input", "Input value cannot be null");
            }
            DataServiceQuery<PlainTextPodEntity> query;
            query = base.CreateQuery<PlainTextPodEntity>("GetPlainTextResults");
            if ((Input != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Input", string.Concat("\'", Input, "\'"));
            }
            if ((Location != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Location", string.Concat("\'", Location, "\'"));
            }
            if ((LatitudeLongitude != null)) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("LatitudeLongitude", string.Concat("\'", LatitudeLongitude, "\'"));
            }
            if (((Width != null) 
                        && (Width.HasValue == true))) {
                query = query.AddQueryOption("Width", Width.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's see the first snippets of code where you are having compile problems - and provide the compile errors. Even though you have provided links to what you are using for an example, we can't assume that your code is identical to the samples. :)

Comment: When I copied and pasted I got the error: does not contain a static 'Main' method. But I am on uncertain where to but the void Main() in the code.

Comment: It sounds like you have deleted the `Program` class/file or you deleted the `main` method. Is your project a Console or WinForm app?

Comment: Does your solution have a Program.cs file?

Comment: does your program file contain `static void Main(string[] args) {...}` ?

Comment: just a suggestion... I ask all my Mathematica/Wolfram questions over at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com - not as active as SO but way more specialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This codeplex project claims to cover the latest Wolfram Alpha API and includes a sample:
http://wolframalphaapi20.codeplex.com/

Console applications use a static Main method as their entry point. This routine can normally be found in a file program.cs that is created automatically when a new project for a console application is created.

If the compiler says it can't find Main then it probably was deleted or was never created. Difficult to say without any code to look at. More errors may show when the issue with the Main method was resolved.

Comment: Link broken. The project doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently playing with a lib call WolframAlpha.NET. Code source is on [github](https://github.com/Genbox/WolframAlpha.NET). There is a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WolframAlpha.NET) (Last published 2019-06-24).

#### Examples (from readme)

Here is the simplest form of getting data from Wolfram|Alpha:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //First create the main class:
    WolframAlpha wolfram = new WolframAlpha("APPID HERE");

    //Then you simply query Wolfram|Alpha like this
    //Note that the spelling error will be correct by Wolfram|Alpha
    QueryResult results = wolfram.Query("Who is Danald Duck?");

    //The QueryResult object contains the parsed XML from Wolfram|Alpha. Lets look at it.
    //The results from wolfram is split into "pods". We just print them.
    if (results != null)
    {
        foreach (Pod pod in results.Pods)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pod.Title);
            if (pod.SubPods != null)
            {
                foreach (SubPod subPod in pod.SubPods)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(subPod.Title);
                    Console.WriteLine(subPod.Plaintext);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more examples, take a look at the WolframAlphaNet.Examples and WolframAlphaNet.Tests projects.

Answer (score 1):

You have copy-pasted class definitions (like `DefaultPodEntity` and `WolframAlphaFactsContainer`) that allow you to interact with the Wolfram API, but you do not have a definition for the `Main()` function that defines what your program should be doing with those classes.  You will need to add the method definition

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // TODO: call methods of WolframAlphaFactsContainer
}
```

to one of the classes (e.g. `WolframAlphaFactsContainer` or a new one, like `Program`, that is not listed in your question.  Once this compiles, you need to replace the `TODO` comment with C# statements that specify how you are interacting with the `WolframAlphaFactsContainer` class (e.g. create an instance of that class and call its `GetImageResults()` method with the proper parameters).

*Note*: you will need to learn basic C# programming idioms before you can successfully tackle the problem of writing a working, correct program in C# that does what *you* want to do (as opposed to relying on other people's code).

*Note*: Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) on `Main()` and how to pass command line parameters to your program (should you want to do that).

*Note*: the class `WolframAlphaFactsContainer` is marked `partial`, which means there might be other parts of this class (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)).  If there are, you will need to include those in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but seeing as how it comes up in google near the top:
https://wapiex.codeplex.com/

This is the wrapper I just finished.  It includes much more than the other codeplex project. Feel free to use it

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I will ask. Why did you choose codeplex instead of github ?

Comment: I honestly don't remember.  I normally use github, but for some reason I used codeplex that time....  and I can't remember the reason. :/